# JSON Date object from REST web services

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am producing json output from REST web services. I have two methods as below.

getProject() - Returns ProjectDO Java bean from Oracle DB
getAudit() - Returns AuditDO Java bean from Oracle DB

Here problem is, the json format of ProjectDO bean returns the Date attribute as **{"date_modified":"2013-05-14"}**, but the json format of AuditDO  bean returns the Date attribute as **{"date_modified":"2016-03-14T00:00:00"}**

I want **{"date_modified":"2013-05-14"}** format. How can I change this format.

Below is the Project Bean

```
public Date date_modified;

public Date getDate_modified() {
    return date_modified;
}
public void setDate_modified(Date date_modified) {
    this.date_modified = date_modified;
}
```

Below is the Audit Bean
    public Date date_modified;

```
public Date getDate_modified() {
    return date_modified;
}
public void setDate_modified(Date date_modified) {
    this.date_modified = date_modified;
}
```

Comment: use SimpleDateFormat when getting date as string http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Which library do you use to generate JSON? GSON? Jackson? Each of them allows you to specify formatters for a property or a type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to convert date from `"2016-03-14T00:00:00"` format to `"2016-03-14"`. If yes, then you can do that by using `SimpleDateFormat` class as given below.

```
//input format
String strDate = "2016-03-14T00:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat oDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date dateObj = oDateFormat.parse(strDate);

//output format
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strNewDate = outputFormat.format(dateObj);

System.out.println(strNewDate);
```